# Form Submit is not Working in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have created a html form in Laravel, But when i submit,it's not submitted and even doesn't show any error.
Here is my form:

```
<form action="{{route('assign.role')}}" method="post">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     @foreach($users as $user)
       <tr>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}} <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}"></td>
        <!-- <td>{{$user->roles->implode('name', ', ')}}</td> -->
        @foreach($roles as $role)
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="role" {{ $user->roles->contains($role) ? 'checked' : '' }}></td>
        @endforeach
        <td><input type="submit" name=""></td>
       </tr>
     @endforeach 
</form>
```

Here, is the Route.

```
Route::post('/assign',[
  'uses' => 'AppController@assignrole',
  'as' => 'assign.role',
  'middleware'=>'roles',
  'roles'=>['Admin']
]);
```

and, my Controller method.

```
public function assignrole(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```

Comment: Have u cheked it without middleware ?

Comment: yes.not respond.

Comment: 'roles' => ['Admin'] doesn't seem to be a valid parameter. Can you try removing that and your middleware, and posting something to it? also, submit inputs don't require name=""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could not use multiple submit for one form

```
     @foreach($users as $user)
<form action="{{route('assign.role')}}" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

    <tr>

        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}} <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}"></td>
        <!-- <td>{{$user->roles->implode('name', ', ')}}</td> -->
        @foreach($roles as $role)
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="role" {{ $user->roles->contains($role) ? 'checked' : '' }}></td>
        @endforeach


        <td><input type="submit" name=""></td>
    </tr>

</form>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: I'm try this your way, It's still not response.

Comment: was the original question edited? i dont see the difference between the answer and the original question

Comment: @Screwtape007 the submit input should not be in foreach loop